# Getting VSCode Marketplace to update Readme

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a vscode extension that I've published before and never had an issue but in the last 2 versions of the extension, the readme does not seem to be updating in the vscode marketplace.

[Extension Snippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devonray.snippet)

[Snippet Github](https://github.com/devon2018/snippet)

Anyone facing any similar issues, and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the problem was here, but publishing a new version today seemed to update the readme.